# rails: sort a has_many using :order is not working due to order by timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-list

I have a rails model let say
User with a has many relationship with Post. Post contains an attribute named position that stores the position (acts_as_list gem). The position stores the position on the user Post list (the order is not due to creation/modification of the post).
Moreover, the Post has timestamps stored (`t.timestamps` in the migration)

So I have defined the following in User.rb:

```
has_many :post, :order => "position", :dependent => :destroy
```

However, when i do a `User.first.posts` The posts are not ordered by position.
I've cheked and the sql being queries contains the following:

```
ORDER BY post.created_at DESC, position
```

So the created_at is still being used.

How can I sort by position and not use the created_at attribute?

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**
I had a default scope degined in Post that was creating the undesired order by.

Problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [default scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_position, order("position ASC")
  default_scope by_position
  #...
end
```

Then `@user.posts` should return a list ordered by the position (ASC).

Also, the following should be working for you: (plural on `post`)

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy, :order => "posts.position ASC"
```